# Отправка в сообщество Viber Bot API

Tags: бот, viber

Возможно ли отправлять ботом через API Вайбера посты в сообщества и групповые чаты?

В документации ничего дельного не нашёл, гугление тоже мало помогло.

Заранее спасибо.